# como passar corretamente os dados de arquivo txt para uma lista no python?

Tags: banco-de-dados, python-3.x, lista, algoritmo-de-busca

Eu estou criando um programa simples que lê os dados de um arquivo `.txt`, passando eles para uma lista. Depois o programa pergunta por uma palavra-chave para verificar se ela existe na lista e mostrar em qual posição ela se encontra.

A priori está dando para pegar os dados do arquivo e passar para a lista, mas quando roda o código de procurar a palavra chave o código só funciona direito quando a palavra-chave está na posição 0 da lista. Quando está na posição 1 para cima, ele já não roda direito, não encontrando a palavra-chave, mesmo digitando certinho.

Fiz um outro arquivo `.py` com o mesmo código, mas com a lista criada no próprio código — sem pegar os dados do arquivo de texto — e o programa funcionou corretamente, encontrando a posição de qualquer elemento que tinha na lista.

Por isso eu acho que o erro está no código que obtém os dados do arquivo `.txt` e cria a lista. Mas eu não faço ideia do que está errado, porque eu já refiz e testei esse código trocentas vezes e não encontrei o erro.

Eis o código problemático:

```
Lista = []

with open(Arquivo, 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as f:
    Dados = f.readlines()

for linha in Dados:
    for i in linha.split(','):
        Lista.append(i)
        print(Lista)
```

Pelo o que eu vejo, a criação da lista está aparentemente normal, mas o código que procura a palavra-chave não está conseguindo iterar por toda a lista.

Esse é o código que procura a palavra-chave na lista:

```
for item in Lista:
    print(item, Lista.index(item))

    if item == Keyword:
       print("Foi encontrada a palavra-chave na lista, na posição: ", Lista.index(Keyword))
```

Atualização

Mudei o código de busca pra esse:

```
for item in Lista:
print(item, Lista.index(item))
if item != Keyword:
    print('A palavra-chave não está na lista')
else:
    print("Foi encontrada a palavra-chave na lista, na posição: ", Lista.index(Keyword))
```

Agora eu obtive a seguinte resposta:

Insira uma lista em formato .txt: C:\Users\Suu\Documents\Lista de games.txt

['a']

['a', ' b']

['a', ' b', ' c']

['a', ' b', ' c', ' d']

Dê uma palavra-chave: b

a 0

A palavra-chave não está na lista

b 1

A palavra-chave não está na lista

c 2

A palavra-chave não está na lista

d 3

A palavra-chave não está na lista

Process finished with exit code 0

Não sei mais o que fazer, sinceramente... Acho que vou desistir mesmo. ='(

Atualização2

Quem quiser ver o código completo pode acessar por este link do meu github:
https://github.com/Suu021/Python-Projects-from-beginner/blob/Suu021-patch-1/Busca%20por%20Brute%20Force.py

Comment: E qual é o conteúdo do arquivo txt?

Comment: De qualquer forma, dá pra ser mais simples: https://repl.it/@hkotsubo/RipeCoolProject#main.py

Answer (score 1):

O seguinte código está funcionando:

```
lista1 = [1,2,2,3,4,5,6,6,6,6,7,8,9,10]

keyword = 2

for index in range(0,len(lista1)):
    # print(index)
    
    if lista1[index] == keyword:
        print(f'Foi encontrada a palavra-chave na lista na posição {index}')
```

resultado:

```
Foi encontrada a palavra-chave na lista na posição 1
Foi encontrada a palavra-chave na lista na posição 2
```

Replicando o seu código, o que eu imagino que acontece é que o método `Lista.index(Keyword)` retorna apenas o mesmo valor pois: 1) Keyword é constante (imagino eu) e 2) esse método retorna apenas a primeira comparação que der `True` (não sei se é isso mesmo não)

Comment: "1) Keyword é constante (imagino eu)"
Keyword é uma variável, o usuário escolhe uma keyword.


"2) esse método retorna apenas a primeira comparação que der True (não sei se é isso mesmo não)"
Sim, é pra retornar a primeira comparação que der True. O problema é que quando a lista é criada a partir do anexo de dados de um arquivo txt, quando o código começa iterar pela lista, ele ta iterando só o primeiro elemento na posição 0. Não ta comparando com o resto dos elementos dentro da lista...

Answer (score 0):

Hoje consegui fazer o meu código rodar do jeito que eu queria, gostaria de expor a minha solução pra ajudar alguém que tenha um problema parecido:

```
with open(Arquivo, 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as f:
dados = f.readlines()
for linha in dados:
    for i in linha.split(', '):
        lista.append(i)
```

O problema tava exatamente na linha 4 desse trecho do código, que antes estava `for i in linha.split(','):`, daquela maneira ao dar o `split` as palavras iam pra lista com um espaço entre elas de maneira que a Keyword informada não batia com aquelas palavras da lista.

Ex: `keyword = 'b'`, `lista = ['a', ' b', ' c', ' d']`.

Do jeito que está agora `for i in linha.split(', '):` a lista fica:
`lista = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']`, sem espaços entre palavras.